# Bob will cook tomorrow or Bob will be cooking tomorrow. What's the difference of meaning?

Tags: future-constructions

I wonder if I understand these two examples right.

*Bob will cook tomorrow.* - I'm predicting the future. There's no emphasis on any existing plans.

*Bob will be cooking tomorrow.* - I'm saying that there's an arrangement made (the decision exists) about Bob cooking tomorrow.
This sentence can be used interchangeably with these:
"Bob is cooking tomorrow." or "Bob is going to cook tomorrow."

Have I grasped all the nuances?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Future tense vs Future continuous tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/82210/future-tense-vs-future-continuous-tense)

Comment: While closely related I do not think this is a duplicate. The distinction this question seeks to draw is different than the one the linked question seeks to draw, although the grammar is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all of these sentences can be and are used interchangeably. There may or may not be a clear plan, but no one  of:

> - Bob will cook tomorrow.
> - Bob will be cooking tomorrow.
> - Bob is cooking tomorrow.
> - Bob is going to cook tomorrow.

implies such a plan more strongly than another. Additional context is needed to determine if there is a fixed plan, or if the speaker is predicting from some other basis.